# Flutter won't compile a release build of my app?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, cocoapods

After working on this app I tried to build my app to iOS using the `flutter run --release` command. But whenever I do I get this error `*Could not build the precompiled application for the device.*`

I've tried `flutter clean` then `flutter upgrade`. I've switched flutter branches. I'm so lost on this one!

Here's the terminal output:

```
Building com.example.projectqr for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: HRCH36A6AR
Running pod install...                                             872ms
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            3.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[9606]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerRestoreInfoHelper is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1fde65eb0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1085f84f8).
    One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[9606]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareAggregateRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1fde65f00) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice
    (0x1085f8548). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[9606]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1fde65f50) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice
    (0x1085f8598). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[9606]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABFile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1fde65fa0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1085f85e8). One of
    the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[9606]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareCopier is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1fde65ff0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1085f8638).
    One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[9606]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABSubfile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1fde66040) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1085f8688). One of
    the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    2022-04-26 18:57:12.964 xcodebuild[9606:80050] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in
    com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-04-26 18:57:12.964 xcodebuild[9606:80050] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/4v/gxt19vmx267662mjsmfhf8mc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.WkwIsq/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirgZNqVy/temporary_xcresult_bundle


    Failed to package /Users/adamjackson/Documents/Github/projectQR/Flutter.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/4v/gxt19vmx267662mjsmfhf8mc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.WkwIsq/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirgZNqVy/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Encountered error while building for device.
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution!

The problem ended up being that CocoaPod wasn't installed correctly.

After digging for what felt like a lifetime! I installing HomeBrew again, then reinstalled cocoapod using `brew install cocoapods` command. After that I ran `flutter clean` and followed that with `flutter run` and it signed the app and launched it on my iPhone!

Thanks for ideas and helping me figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

*1. execute*

```
Flutter Clean
```

*then*

2. Remove the simulator from Xcode and re-add a new simulator

*then*

3. Re-run your app in flutter and it would be

further solution :

- Open iOS module in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried your steps but sadly I'm getting the same error? Also I'm trying to put the app on my physical iPhone (iPhone 13 running iOS version 15.4.1)

Comment: You have to run flutter build in ios physical device by providing debug certificates inside signing & capabilities section.

Comment: Try that command "flutter build ios --debug --no-codesign --simulator"

Comment: I tired "flutter build ios --debug --no-codesign --simulator" it gave me Runner.app file. But when I tried it again after messing with Pod it broke... Yeah

Comment: You can drag and drop the .app file on your simulator and It will running .